# Recognizing UIButton from a loop

Tags: iphone, loops, uibutton

I've seen one question/answer with a result similar to what I'm looking for, but the code discussed was much more complicated than I have right now.

I'm using a for() loop to create a bunch of a buttons from an array. Then, I have an action, but I'm unable to recognize the button. So:

```
NSArray *numbers = [NSArray arrayWithOjbects:@"1", "2", "3", nil];

for (int i = 0; i <  [numbers count]; i++) {

   button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   [button addTarget:self action:@selector(recognize:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
   [button setTitle:[numbers objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, l);

   }
```

Then:

```
-(void) recognize:(id)sender {

   NSLog (button.titleLabel.text);

 }
```

But, I only get the last member of the array (3) regardless of button pressed. I think I'm missing a step in -(void) recognize:(id)sender... that I should be know... but it's completely escaping me right now.

/Vlad

Comment: Do you add them somewhere on your view? There is a property `tag` for the purpose of identifying elements. At the end of loop you should do something like `[self.view addSubview:button]`

Comment: Yes, with: [board addSubview:button] just a bit later. I forgot to add before because between it and the rest of the code were the recalculations for position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each iteration of the loop assigns to the `button` variable.  When the loop is exited, it will simply hold the last value you assigned to it.  The `button` variable appears to be an instance variable - it's unique to the instance of the class, not to the button.

The convenient way of doing what you want is to access the `sender` variable, which iOS supplies to your method.  This holds the object that produced the event in question, in this case, the button.

```
NSLog (@"%@", ((UIButton *)sender).titleLabel.text);
```

Also note that it's not acceptable to log a text value in that way.  If it contains a format string (such as `%@`), it will expect a further argument, which it doesn't get, and will crash.  **This can be a security hole.**  When you have a string variable that you want to log, use `%@` to log it, as above.  Xcode should already be warning you about this.  Do not ignore warnings.

Comment: Thank you very much, and duly noted about sloppy use of NSLog.