# Recognizing all objects generated by a loop

Tags: iphone, loops, uitextfield

This question is a bit related to one I posed previously entitled "[Recognizing UIButton from a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694165/recognizing-uibutton-from-a-loop)".

In this case, I have generated a bunch of UITextFields with a loop. When the value of one of them is changed, I'm able to recognize which textfield it was.

However, I want to then edit every textfield that was generated. Specifically, I get input from the one textfield that was edited, and I want to recalculate the other textfields based on the input and name of the recognized textfield.

How do I call for every one of the other generated, non-edited textfields to be modified?

/Vlad

Comment: The code in the answer below doesn't work (I couldn't fix the errors it was returning).
I'll try to re-explain what I am try to do.
I've defined a UITextField *textfield. I loop it. So I have a bunch of these textFields. I add a tag. I recognize which field it was by the tag. Now, based on field and its contents, I want to then modify all the other textfields.

Comment: So for example, if the input in the edited textField (e.g. tag = 3) was "5", I want to divide the contents of all the other contents by the tag number time the content. So for tag=1, the result would be (original * 3/5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using tags, this is what `viewWithTag` is used for:

```
// Get a reference to the textfield with tag 3
UITextField *textField3 = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:3];

// Calculate your new value
float result = 4.32; // Calculate the value that you want the textfield with tag 3 to display

// Change the contents
textField3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", result];
```

Comment: I get an exception: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to ..."

Comment: then the subview of the current view that has tag 3 is not a textField...  :)

Comment: I tested something that I knew for sure was a text field and a tag (by logging it). I will indeed try to find why tag3 isn't one... because the only fields I'm assigning a tag to are UITextFields... however, I may be skipping numbers with an if()... have to check this out carefully.

Comment: You can try adding `NSLog (%@"textfield3: %@: Class: %@", textField3, [textField3 class]);` immediately after the viewWithTag line to see what is returned.

Comment: Nulls: textfield3: (null): Class: (null)

Comment: That's what I suspected.  There is no subview in this view controller's view that has a tag of 3....

Comment: I was trying to do an NSLog of the textfields as they were to see that everything was connecting. Only problem with that is that those fields were all null, so it caused a crash. So now there are no problems. Thank you for your answer and patience.

Answer (score 0):

store the text fields in an array, then when you want to change the value

```
[self.myTextFieldArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UITextField *textField, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    if (![textField isEqual:theTextFieldThatWasEdited])
        textField.text = @"whatever text you want";
}];
```